# Submitting one form to multiple controllers

Tags: javascript, forms, spring-mvc

I have a form in which some fields must be submitted to one controller and other fields to another controller.  There is also some overlap.

I need to submit these fields via an ajax call(s).

What's the best way to do this in Spring 3 MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Gather the data with javascript (jquery). Do that by id / name, regardless of the fact they are in on form.
2. Make two separate ajax requests to two different urls, mapping two different methods